# Asus touchpad won't work in Linx Mint

Tags: touchpad

My touchpad does not work in Linux Mint, which I recently installed. I can connect a mouse and it works fine. I have an Asus Zenbook Pro UX501 laptop.

I tried a bunch of things, but none of them worked. I checked in hardware >> mouse and touchpad, and the touchpad was turned on according to the settings. I tried pressing the F9 key on my keyboard which looks like a mouse with a line through it, but the exact same shape with the line appears on the screen which, means it is turned off, I assume. I also installed touchpad-indicator, but it won't run for some reason on my Linux.

Also, when I run dmesg | grep mouse, this is what I get:

[ 0.918702] mousedev: PS/2 mouse device common for all mice

I ran:

```
 cat /proc/bus/input/devices
```

and I got a block with the touchpad in it:

```
I: Bus=0003 Vendor=0457 Product=10cc Version=0111
   N: Name="USBest Technology SiS HID Touch Controller"
   P: Phys=usb-0000:00:14.0-12/input0
   S: Sysfs=/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb1/1-12/1-12:1.0/0003:0457:10CC.0002/input/input5
   U: Uniq=
   H: Handlers=mouse1 event5 
   B: PROP=2
   B: EV=b
   B: KEY=400 0 0 0 0 0
   B: ABS=260800000000003
```

Comment: Model would be helpful...

Comment: Zenbook Pro UX501

Comment: I did. 3 things that I mentioned in the second paragraph are all that I found in the forums, and none of them worked for me.

Comment: I did, and I got this:

Comment: [ 0.918702] mousedev: PS/2 mouse device common for all mice

Comment: Done. It appears with and without a mouse

Comment: That's your touch screen - was there anything else?

Comment: Is this one for the touchpad?

I: Bus=0011 Vendor=0001 Product=0001 Version=ab41
N: Name="AT Translated Set 2 keyboard"
P: Phys=isa0060/serio0/input0
S: Sysfs=/devices/platform/i8042/serio0/input/input3
U: Uniq=
H: Handlers=sysrq kbd event3 
B: PROP=0
B: EV=120013
B: KEY=402000000 3803078f800d001 feffffdfffefffff fffffffffffffffe
B: MSC=10
B: LED=7

Comment: I know it says keyboard but it's the closest I found! If it's not that, then It's not there

Comment: That looks like your keyboard.  If it's not there, then it suggests that your kernel doesn't recognise the brand of touchpad in your laptop. If you're dual-booting with Windows, you could try and boot there and see if you can find any useful nuggets.  If not, you can try the latest kernel, but that could involve compiling it!

Comment: Sorry what's a nugget? And how would I try the latest kernel?

Comment: A nugget: 1.2 [here](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/nugget). If your Linux Mint is the latest version with all updates applied, then your options for applying the latest kernel is to download the latest `.deb` file as explained [here](https://mintguide.org/system/561-install-linux-kernel-4-4-lts-on-linux-mint.html) or [compile your own](https://forums.linuxmint.com/viewtopic.php?t=131433).

Comment: Since Mint is Ubuntu based try on [Askubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/). Maybe have something to do with the move from synaptics to libinput. Try removing and adding kernel module: `sudo modprobe -r psmouse` then same without `-r`. Now listed on `xinput list`?

Answer (score -1):

I understand in linux they might be missing some driver files one way to chk is to reinstall you linux.